# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' в AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Открываю проект (opensource) посмотреть реализацию. Все вроде нормально, но ругается на R:

```
 @Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mAuthor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author);
    mPubDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pub_date);
}
```

Что это означает и какие есть способы решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В AndroidStudio `File->InvalidateCahces`. Можно еще `Build->Clean Project`.

**Обновление**

Если вы открываете проект взятый, например, из GitHub, и меняете, например, имя пакета, то данные о путях к классам которые хранятся в кэше соответственно другие. Когда вы очищаете кеш, система подхватывает изменения.

Comment: Работает! А почему нужно каждый раз очищать кеш?

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно нажать `Sync Project with Gradle files` . Мне помог.

[image: Sync Project with Gradle files]

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это: установить Compile Sdk Version на последнюю.
http://dominoc925.blogspot.ru/2014/11/fixing-android-studio-cannot-resolve.html

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло изменение compileSdkVersion в build.gradle для приложения, на версию соответствующую compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:'
У меня compileSdkVersion 26, com.android.support:appcompat-v7: 26.1.0 
система mac os hight sierra android studio 3.1